# Debugging Loop for numerical iterations

Tags: vba, excel

I was creating a critical value approximator of American style options. I was getting the error "#Value!" only after around 40 loops (kept track with a counter).

After some trial and error I realized it came from the part of the loop calling the BlackScholes pricing function. In theory I want to run through a range of values iteratively for the spot price while keeping the other variables fixed in a Black Scholes European price calculation. After tinkering around I reduced the issue to the fact that after the first loop it was no longer calculating Black Scholes the way it would if I just used the value on that iteration and the value I was getting was just increasing by 1, then crapping out after 40 loops of wrong values for some non obvious reason.

So below I truncated the code to a very simple skeleton which is the essence of my problem. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 Function Looper(S As Double, K As Double, r As Double, t As Double, q As Double, Vol As Double) As Double
  Dim i As Double
For i = 100 To 150 Step 1#

MsgBox i
MsgBox BS(i, K, r, t, q, Vol, "Call") 'After the first loop the values are wrong, 
'What I'd like is, BS(100,...), BS(101,...),BS(102,...) which it is not. 
'Not sure what it's actually calculating, since the values are way off

  Next i

End Function

Public Function BS(S As Double, K As Double, r As Double, t As Double, q As Double, Vol As Double, CP As String) As Double

Dim volrootime As Double
Dim d1 As Double
Dim d2 As Double
Dim DiscF As Double
Dim DivF As Double
Dim topline1 As Double
Dim topline2 As Double
Dim topline As Double
Dim Price As Double

t = t / 365
r = r / 100
q = q / 100



DiscF = Exp(-r * t)
DivF = Exp(-q * t)
volrootime = (t ^ 0.5) * Vol


    topline1 = Log(S / K)
    topline2 = ((r - q) + ((Vol ^ 2) / 2)) * t
    topline = topline1 + topline2
    d1 = topline / volrootime
    d2 = d1 - volrootime

    If CP = "Call" Then

        ' Theta is in terms of Calendar days, changing the denominator to 252 changes it to trading days


        Price = (S * DivF * Bign(d1)) - (K * DiscF * Bign(d2))


 Else

    ' Theta is in terms of Calendar days, changing the denominator to 252 changes it to trading days



        Price = K * DiscF * Bign(-d2) - S * DivF * Bign(-d1)


End If
BS = Price
 End Function
```

Comment: Are you using Option Explicit? Often these problems are caused by a typo which generates a different variable to the one you expect.

Comment: Yes using option explicit. I checked around for similar issues. I tried making i a public variable outside the function as well because that seemed to fix some people's problems but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of r, t, q change each time the BS function is called. If they must stay constant, you should use ByVal in the BS function declaration like this:

```
BS(S As Double, K As Double, ByVal r As Double, ByVal t As Double, ByVal q As Double, ...
```

By default, the parameters are passed by reference and any change in the called function are reflected in the calling function.

By the way, in this example, I wouldn't use messageboxes when debugging but instead use `debug.print` like this:

```
Debug.Print "i=" & i & vbTab & "BS=" & BS(i, K, r, t, q, Vol, "Call")
```

The print is made in the window opened by pressing Ctl + G (Go To).

Comment: Of course, they're getting scaled every loop. So simple. Thank you